# can not find easyhook64.dll

Tags: inject, dll-injection, easyhook, api-hook

I downloaded easyhook package "EasyHook 2.7.6789.0 Binaries .NET 3.5/4.0 (zip)" and then link dll with my project in visual studio 2015 (first add my easyhook in this path C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories and second add .lib file to Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies). No errors occur in build but when I run got this error "can not find easyhook64.dll".

Answer (score 0):

The EasyHook binaries need to be located in the same dir as your exe at runtime.